# Want to Understand logic behind Template Methods

Tags: java, android, oop

Guys I just want to clear my doubt on working of Abstract Class methods. Hope I will get a satisfied answer.

We have `Class Base`(abstract class) and `Class Derived`(concrete class) defined like so:

```
abstract class Base {
   abstract public void operation_first();

   public void operation_second{
      operation_first();
   }
}

class Derived extends Base {
   public void operation_first{
     //Implementation
   }
}
```

Now when we call `operation_second` method like as

```
new Derived().operaton_second();
```

it always calls Derived Class `operation_first` method.
I just want to know the logic behind this approach where Base class called derived class method.

Comment: you are calling the operation_first() method  inside the operaitions_second() so its calling

Comment: abstract methods are needed to be overrided thats only they are called as abstract methods.. so whenver you a calling a abstract methods it ll always call your derived class overrided methods... thats all

Comment: ya i knew i called operation_first() method inside the operation_second() method but i want to know why it's happening.

Comment: it will assist you http://www.javatpoint.com/abstract-class-in-java

Comment: i try it, but it's not helping me.my doubt is still not clear,how operation_first() method is calling here

Comment: i give you another scenario if we have more then one derived class which extends base class and then how operation_first() method know in which class it needs to be go.

Answer (score 0):

This is called "late binding". The only class function `operation_first` is implemented in is Derived and thanks to the late binding Base class knows of this implementation.

Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding

Answer (score 0):

I use this pattern when there are several (related) classes which have common code. You can put the common part in the base class and put the specific code in the derived classes, your operation_first method. In the base class you can then have one method (this will be your operation_second method) in which you put the operation flow which is the same for all the derived classes. This way you can remove the duplicate code and have the operation flow in a central place.

```
public abstract class AbstractMessageHandler<T extends RequestMessage>() {
    public ResponseMessage process(T requestMessage) {
        // some common logic

        validate(requestMessage);

        // some more common logic

        Transaction transaction = getTransaction(requestMessage);

        // some more common logic

        ResponseMessage response = processTransaction(transaction, requestMessage);

        // some more common logic

        return response;
    }

    protected abstract boolean validate(T requestMessage);

    protected abstract Transaction getTransaction(T requestMessage)

    protected abstract ResponseMessage processTransaction(Transaction transaction, T requestMessage);

}
```

Example of code which calls the process method using a Strategy pattern. EXECUTOR_MAP contains all concrete implementations of the AbstractMessageHandler.

```
public ResponseMessage execute(RequestMessage requestMessage)
        throws MessageHandlerNotFoundException {

    if (requestMessage == null) {            
        throw new MessageHandlerNotFoundException(
                "Request message is null so no message handler could be found.");
    }

    MessageHandler messageHandler = EXECUTOR_MAP.get(requestMessage.getMessageTypeIdentifier());
    if (messageHandler == null) {            
        throw new MessageHandlerNotFoundException("No message handler found for message: "
                + requestMessage.getClass().getName());
    }

    ResponseMessage ctepMessageResponse = messageHandler.process(requestMessage);
    return ctepMessageResponse;
}
```

Comment: how can be operation_first method call from superclass , we call operation_second method with derived Class instance but how operation_first method is calling here,how it would know the derived class object reference.

Comment: Well you would call the operation_second method on the derived class, so that operation_second will call the operation_first method from the same (derived) class.